# Unable to run Genymotion inside VMWare

Tags: android, opengl-es, virtualbox, vmware, genymotion

I have a problem running Genymotion "inside" VMWare that is running on Windows 7 32-bit. It gives me an error "Unable to initialize OpenGL renderer library.". At first, I didn't notice the version of the OpenGL of my guest (Windows 7 32-bit) is 1.1 or 1.4 (I can't remember) then I read some solutions online on how to update the driver to 2.1 but still, Genymotion is giving me the same error. I tried to uninstall Genymotion and reinstalling it again but unfortunately, the problem is still there.

I also read on a blog that the user was able to run Genymotion on VMWare with Windows XP I also tried that too but it didn't worked for me. Then I installed it on the host (I am running Windows 8 with OpenGL 4.x) and it worked.

Here's the result of the test I did with glewinfo.exe to see the version of OpenGL my guest is running: http://pastebin.com/ncZv58DV

Comment: "I also read on a blog that the user was able to run [...]" mind to post the link?

Comment: Here it is http://forum.projectanarchy.com/showthread.php?690-Has-anyone-tried-an-x86-Android-build

Comment: So it just looks like OpenGL acceleration is not enabled. (Is it?) Check that setting: http://pubs.vmware.com/fusion-4/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.fusion.help.doc/GUID-C0E9FDAC-BC40-4A6B-8940-013597CA5E5B.html

Comment: Well, I saw that page before. It's enabled mate. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, Genymotion needs a direct access to the hardware in order to provide OpenGL acceleration. Running Genymotion from a virtual machine prevents it to directly access the hardware components.

https://www.genymotion.com/faq/#virtual-machine-start-impossible

Answer (score 0):

For 2023, the issue comes from Virtual Box, not Genymotion.
In my case, to make the Emulator work, you just have to pass the Hardware Acceleration to the VM:

[image: Enable Hardware Acceleration - VMWare]

After this, you need to close Genymotion, open Virtual Box in your VMWare Machine and enable 3D Acceleration and change the driver to VMSVGA:

[image: Enable 3D - Virtual Box]